# firestore onSuccess listener isn't working

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to download some Quiz objects from my database.
The following function is called from onCreate of a certain activity.

```
 private void downloadQuizzesFromCloud(){

        String user_id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        String user_quizzes_path = "users/".concat(user_id).concat("/quizzes");
        Query userQuizzes = db.collection(user_quizzes_path);

        userQuizzes.get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            quizzes.clear();
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                                Quiz quizDownloaded = getQuizFromCloud(document.getId());
                                quizzes.add(quizDownloaded);
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(QuizzesActivity.this,"downloaded to list ".concat(String.valueOf(quizzes.size()).concat("  quizzes")), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //TODO put in recycle adapter
                        } else { }
                    }
                });

    }
```

(user_quizzes_path contains the correct path to a collection of Quiz objects stored on the cloud)

I debugged this functions and found out that after the command:

```
 userQuizzes.get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>()
```

The function finishes execution, that is the onComplete cases aren't checked and executed and all this code is just skipped.

I tried to find this on the documentation of firebase but didn't find anything.
Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Would appreciate some help here, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `onComplete` is called when the read operation has completed from the Firestore servers. If it's not getting called, I can see two possible reasons:

1. You're not connected to the server. Unless you've read the data before (and it's in the local database that the Firestore client maintains), this means the read never completes locally.
2. You're not thinking asynchronously. Note that data is read from the server asynchronously, and there may be some time between when you call `get()` and when `onComplete` fires. To test if this is the case, put a breakpoint on `if (task.isSuccessful()) {` and run the app in the debugger. The breakpoint will hit when the data is read from the server.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is indeed because I am not thinking asynchronously.
How can I make sure that objects I change in my code will change only after the server data read is complete?

Comment: You do that by calling the code from within `onComplete`, since that is the method that fires after the data has loaded.

Comment: this would work however if I were to use the variable "quizzes" somewhere else in my code, (for example just before the function "downloadQuizzesFromCloud" is finished) It is not promised that the task has finished and I could have incorrect data in "quizzes" variable. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Any code that depends on the quizes that are loaded asynchronously from the database should be either inside the `onComplete` (that is called when the data has loaded) or called from within that method. I commented the same on your previous question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53970276/firestore-read-is-asynchronous-and-i-want-synchronous-behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Use a callback interface. Just like this below.

```
private void downloadQuizzesFromCloud(Consumer listener) {

    String user_id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    String user_quizzes_path = "users/".concat(user_id).concat("/quizzes");

    Query userQuizzes = db.collection(user_quizzes_path);

    userQuizzes.get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        List<Quiz> quizzes = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Quiz quizDownloaded = getQuizFromCloud(document.getId());
                            quizzes.add(quizDownloaded);
                        }
                        listener.onGet(quizzes);
                        Toast.makeText(QuizzesActivity.this,"downloaded to list ".concat(String.valueOf(quizzes.size()).concat("  quizzes")), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //TODO put in recycle adapter
                    } else { }
                }
            });

 } 
 interface Consumer {
    void onGet(List<Quiz> quizzes);
 }
```

Comment: I want to acheive something like this:

downloadQuizzesFromCloud();
print(quizzes);

and I want that quizzes will be updated when I print them. How does can I do this with a callback interface?

Comment: Call `downloadQuizzesFromCloud(this::print)` and declare a function
`private void print(List<Quiz> quizzes) {
// do everything here.
}`.

If you're using JAVA-7 then do this following, `downloadQuizzesFromCloud(this)` and implement the `onGet(List<Quiz> quizzes)` function